# Removing numbers that are negative from SQL query

Tags: sql, negative-number

How do you remove negative numbers from SQL query result.

Example:
Select acquisitionprice-salesprice
From Han.trans

I'm trying to find out the Profit by subtracting two columns from a table and would like to have the **negative numbers** removed from the result

Comment: `WHERE acquisitionprice-salesprice >= 0` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE salesprice > acquisitionprice
```

probably is treated as the same as giorgos-betsos commented

```
WHERE acquisitionprice-salesprice >= 0
```

but reads a little simpler to me.

Comment: Great. And welcome to StackOverflow. Customarily if you find an answer useful you upvote and if it answer your question you accept it, marking it as answered.